# JavaFX Action Event - Pull from Array

Tags: java, javafx

Working on a school project, I am trying to get the action of clicking a button pull the selected index of a Combo Box  string array, and associated that index with an int array so that a final price can be computed. Doesn't seem to work the price just remains at zero when button is pressed.

```
private final String[] deckArray = {"The Master 
     Thrasher ", "The Dictator", "The Street King"};
private final String[] trucksArray = {"7.75-inch 
      axle", "8-inch axle", "8.5-inch axle"};
private final String[] wheelsArray = {"51mm", "55mm", 
      "58mm", "61mm"};
private final int[] deckPrice = {60,45,50};
private final int[] trucksPrice = {35,40,45};
private final int[] wheelsPrice = {20,22,24,28};

comboDecks = new ComboBox();
comboDecks.getItems().addAll(deckArray);
comboTrucks = new ComboBox();
comboTrucks.getItems().addAll(trucksArray);
comboWheels = new ComboBox();
comboWheels.getItems().addAll(wheelsArray);
btnCalc = new Button("Calculate Total");
lblFinalPrice = new Label("Final Price:");
txtSubtotal = new Text("Subtotal: " + finalSubPrice);
txtTax = new Text("Tax:" + finalTaxPrice);
txtFinalPrice = new Text("Final Price: " + 
finalTotalPrice);

EventHandler<ActionEvent> calcHandler = new 
   EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
     @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) { 
       finalDeckPrice = deckPrice[comboDecks.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()];
            finalTruckPrice = trucksPrice[comboTrucks.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()];
            finalWheelsPrice = wheelsPrice[comboWheels.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()];
            finalSubPrice = finalDeckPrice + finalTruckPrice + finalWheelsPrice;
            finalTaxPrice = finalSubPrice * salesTax;
            finalTotalPrice = finalSubPrice + finalTaxPrice;
        }
    };
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the price remains at zero when the button is pressed"? Your event handler computes the price (`finalTotalPrice`), but doesn't do anything with it. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: Just some advice, unrelated to the question. JavaFX is just Java. Try to write code that looks like Java code. Don't use raw types. Instead of arrays of strings and ints, etc., which you have to maintain in order, create classes to represent your data. E.g. you could (should) have an `Item` class with `getPrice()` and `getName()` methods. Then your combo boxes can be `ComboBox<Item>`, and your code becomes a lot more manageable.

Comment: Thank you I greatly appreciate the advice. I definitely want to work on cleaning it up. As for the question I was expecting the txtFinalPrice above the event to reflected the updated finalTotalPrice

Comment: *"I was expecting the txtFinalPrice above the event to reflected the updated finalTotalPrice"*. Why? There is no code in the event handler which does anything to `txtFinalPrice`.

Answer (score 0):

You made the button, you made the event handler, but you never connected the event handler to the button. Same goes for the calculation and the label, you calculated but did not update the label with the calculated value.

1. Add the following line to your code after you create the handler.

```java
btnCalc.setOnAction(calcHandler);
```

2. And add `txtFinalPrice.setText(""+finalTotalPrice);` after you finish calculations inside handle() method.

```java
public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) { 
    ...
    finalTotalPrice = finalSubPrice + finalTaxPrice;
    txtFinalPrice.setText("Final Price: " + finalTotalPrice);
}
```

#### Explanation (Abstract)

- (1) When you create an Event Handler object you just wrote the code you want it to run but it won't run in serial as the code executes top to bottom, since as you said you want it to work when you click the button. So you have to let the Button know that when it gets clicked to execute this code. `setOnAction()` method takes as parameter an Event Handler object and executes it when some action happens to the Button, the action for the Button is when it gets clicked.
- (2) Just by calculating the value, doesn't mean the Label knows that the value got calculated or something. The point where you calculating the price is the point that you have to tell to the Label take this value and use this as your content.

##### Suggestion

Event handlers, action events etc need a bit of good understanding to use them correctly. The baseline is that all of that work `asynchronously` and you gotta get at least the idea of it so you can understand the rest (no offense but from the question i believe you need some work on it).

Comment: `btnCalc.onAction(...)` should be `btnCalc.setOnAction(...)`

Comment: Thanks @James_D, writting it from phone getting soon to pc for extra testing and explanation.